# Silverlight - Lync Application nested in a table

Tags: silverlight-4.0, sdk, lync-2010

I'm very new in Silverlight and the Lync-SDK. So sorry for the question from a beginner.
Long time ago, i wrote al little web application, based on php for reading out contacts from a sql database.

Now the customer expand his envoirement and place Lync. Now he want the little Lync-Status-Square in the webapplication for click to call features.

I playing a little bit with the SDK of lync.

The following problem comes up. The square of Lync is nested in a td of my table. But the Lync-Silverlight-Applet need dynamical space for hover effects or single clicks. But in my table, i have no space, specially dynamic space.

So i switch off all hover and click functionality and place the follwing buttons in the StackPanel separate.

- PresenceIndicator
- StartInstanceMessagingButton
- StartAudiCallButton
- SendEmailButton

Two of them are fine.

Clicking on the IM-Button, The Lync Client opens the right Contact in IM-Mode and i can directly type a message. Perfect!

Clicking on the Mail-Icon, an Mail-Client will open, perfect.

The PresenceIndicator just display the color, not the exactly state, thats a problem, when the color is yellow. I can display the state in a TextBlock, but i prefer a label appears while hovering over the icon.

But my mainproblem is the StartAudioCallButton. This Icon is an dropDown-Icon. And i have no space for dropdowns. I would be so nice if this icon has the same behavoior like the IM-Button. The Lync Client will open in Call Modus and i can select, which callernumber i will use. Is that possible?

Thank you for Your time!
Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're having trouble with the layout of the standard Lync SilverLight controls, then the best thing to do is implement your own SilverLight controls for the function you're having difficulty with.

User Controls are really simple to create, there are plenty of tutorials on how to get started if you're not familiar with the process.

The [Lync SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg421054.aspx) has some great walkthroughs to get you up and running with [signing in to Lync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg437053.aspx) and [placing an audio call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg436797.aspx)

I don't know of any way to get Lync to open in a Call Mode as you suggested, but if you're limited with screen space, maybe you could have your custom StartAudioCallButton open a popup with the phone numbers in?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Thats the preferred way. Just a little userControl and a click action with the callernumber as parameter. As result, the lync-Client should open in the right context. I'll looking over the links and come back. Thanks.

Comment: unfortunately, the project is stopped and the development is not longer requested. Thank you for your answer an sorry for the long delay